# how to log qt exceptions raised in c++ in pyside2

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

I have an QT5/Pyside2 application happily logging into a file. Also exceptions are logged via excepthook:

```py
sys.excepthook = lambda t, value, tb: log.exception(f'{t} {value} {"".join(traceback.format_exception(t, value, tb))}')
```

But some exceptions raised by QT do not seem to pass the handler. They are simply printed to the console.

```
2020-07-14 13:42:51,676 - TRACE - sidewindow::__init__() - new view. call super.
2020-07-14 13:42:51,681 - TRACE - sidewindow::__init__() - show window and append
QWindowsEGLStaticContext::createWindowSurface: Could not create the EGL window surface: 0x3003
qt.qpa.backingstore: composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
createDIB: CreateDIBSection failed (1273x666, format: 6)
```

How can I redirect these Exceptions to a file or make python handle it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem in the past with PyQt, so I wrote a simple module that allows to set output files for both stdout and stderr. The module is called [pyfreopen](https://github.com/MaurizioB/pyfreopen) but has to be compiled.

Unfortunately I did it a lot of time ago, using Python 2.7, so it's possible it won't work on Python 3 (I'll be at home later and will check if it can be built for Python 3 too).

The usage is very simple:

```
freopen.set_stdout(path="stderr.log")
freopen.set_stderr(path="stdout.log")
```

Note that, as explained in the readme, once the output is set, it cannot be restored to the default behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much--unfortunately compiling is not a viable option here.